# Reading data from HDFS - my program can't find the path

Tags: java, hadoop, file-io

I'm trying to read the contents of a file from HDFS. My code is below -

```
package gen;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class ReadFromHDFS {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  if (args.length < 1) {
   System.out.println("Usage: ReadFromHDFS <hdfs-file-path-to-read-from>");
   System.out.println("Example: ReadFromHDFS 'hdfs:/localhost:9000/myFirstSelfWriteFile'");
   System.exit(-1);
  } 

  try {
   Path path = new Path(args[0]);
   FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(path)));
   String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
   while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to give this program the path to my HDFS directory. I have tried -

```
java -cp <hadoop jar:myjar> gen.ReadFromHDFS <path>
```

where with path I tried referencing the directory directly (what I see when I do hadoop fs -ls), the file inside the directory, adding hdfs:/localhost, hdfs:/ and none of them work. Can any one help me with how exactly I should pass the path of my folder to HDFS? For example, when I give the path directly (with no prefix) it says that the file does not exist.

Edit: None of the solutions so far seem to work for me. I always get the exception -

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundExceptoin: File <filename> does not exist.
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.getFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
```

It seems to be trying to find the file locally.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
Path path = new Path(fileSystem.getName() + "/" + args[0]);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(path)));
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

and give file path in HDFS as (with no prefix)

```
"/myFirstSelfWriteFile"
```

do not include "hdfs:/localhost"

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the classes in package org.apache.hadoop.fs (FileSystem, FSDataInputStream, FSDataOutputStream and Path).  There are several articles out there, but I'd use this one from the [Hadoop Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopDfsReadWriteExample)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing one / in your path, should give two /'s after filesystem. Try specifying the following path

```
hdfs://localhost:9000/myFirstSelfWriteFile
```