# Read the data from HDFS using Scala

Tags: scala, hdfs

I am new to Scala. How can I read a file from HDFS using Scala (not using Spark)?
When I googled it I only found writing option to HDFS.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
* @author ${user.name}
*/
object App {

//def foo(x : Array[String]) = x.foldLeft("")((a,b) => a + b)

def main(args : Array[String]) {
println( "Trying to write to HDFS..." )
val conf = new Configuration()
//conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020")
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.30.147:8020")
val fs= FileSystem.get(conf)
val output = fs.create(new Path("/tmp/mySample.txt"))
val writer = new PrintWriter(output)
try {
    writer.write("this is a test") 
    writer.write("\n")
}
finally {
    writer.close()
    println("Closed!")
}
println("Done!")
}

}
```

Please help me.How can read the file or load file from HDFS using scala.

Comment: What did you try so far, e.g. with https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html ?

Comment: hard to follow docs here imho

Comment: We have elected for small files to copy from HDFS to local file system and process there SEQUENTIALLY.

Answer (score 22):

One of the ways (kinda in functional style) could be like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import java.net.URI
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream

val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://yourUrl:port/"), new Configuration()) 
val path = new Path("/path/to/file/")
val stream = hdfs.open(path)
def readLines = Stream.cons(stream.readLine, Stream.continually( stream.readLine))

//This example checks line for null and prints every existing line consequentally
readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(line => println(line))
```

Also you could take a look [this article](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/12/28/Reading-data-from-HDFS-even-if-it-is-compressed.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986887/reading-data-from-hdfs-my-program-cant-find-the-path) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108980/how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs-in-map-quickly-with-spark), these questions look related to yours and contain working (but more Java-like) code examples if you're interested.

Comment: What is `URI`? How do I import this?

Comment: I got this working by importing `URI` as `import java.net.URI` and setting it to `hdfs:///` as my Scala service is running in the same node as the HDFS nameserver host.

Comment: The method readLine is now deprecated, you should use `val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))` on top of the stream object (source and example of use: https://hadoopandspark.wordpress.com/2018/04/23/hadoop-write-and-read-part-1-scala/ )