# How to read a text file from HDFS in Scala natively (without using Spark)?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, text-files, apache-toree

I know I can read a local file in `Scala` like so:

```
import scala.io.Source

val filename = "laba01/ml-100k/u.data"

for(line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines){
    println(line)
}
```

This code words fine and prints out the lines from the text file. I run it in `JupyterHub` with `Apache Toree`.

I know I can read from `HDFS` at this server, because when I run the next code in another cell:

```
import sys.process._
"hdfs dfs -ls /labs/laba01/ml-100k/u.data"!
```

it works fine too, and I can see this output:

```
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs    1979173 2020-04-20 17:56 /labs/laba01/ml-100k/u.data

lastException: Throwable = null
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details

0
```

Now I want to read this same file kept in `HDFS` by running this:

```
import scala.io.Source

val filename = "hdfs:/labs/laba01/ml-100k/u.data"

for(line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines){
    println(line)
}
```

but I get this output instead of the file's lines printed out:

```
lastException = null

Name: java.io.FileNotFoundException
Message: hdfs:/labs/laba01/ml-100k/u.data (No such file or directory)
StackTrace:   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
```

So how do I read this text file from `HDFS`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read the data from HDFS using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587931/read-the-data-from-hdfs-using-scala)

Comment: @mazaneicha no, because 1) it doesn't work and it's kinda old to ask for more explanations there (but I'll try). There's some `URI` object there which leads to `Unknown Error` when I run that code. 2) It needs some host and port, which I don't really care about since I am able to access `HDFS` from the very same server I run my `Scala` code on.

Comment: This is HDFS NameNode's host and port, and you need them to access HDFS file system.

Answer (score 4):

`scala.io` will not able to find any file in HDFS. It's not for that. If I'm not wrong it can only read file that are in your local (`file:///`)

You need to use `hadoop-common.jar` to read the data from HDFS.

You can find code example here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616512/7857701

Comment: That code doesn't work and it's kinda old to ask for more explanations there (but I'll try). There's some URI object there which leads to Unknown Error when I run that code. And it needs some host and port, which I don't really care about since I am able to access HDFS from the very same server I run my Scala code on.

Comment: Yes it needs nameserver host and port. OR If you have the service running in the same node put `hdfs:///` (mind the 3 `/`) in the URI

Comment: What about `URI` in `new URI`? What is it and how do I import it?

Comment: thank you so much! `hdfs:///` did the trick! I imported `URI` as `import java.net.URI`

Comment: Yes thats the one. If your name server is on other node you have specify host:port